# fontspec can not find the font file to work on Mac OS

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I am using texlive2018 and trying to make a simple tex file using `xeCJK` to work on Mac OS, but the `fontspec` can not find the font file even I am using a western character set font file.

The test.tex file is like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra,fontspec,xunicode}
\usepackage[slantfont,boldfont]{xeCJK} % xeCJK

\setmonofont{Monaco}   % set font

\begin{document}
\begin{verse}
  Stray birds of summer come to my window to sing and fly away. \\
  And yellow leaves of autumn, which have no songs, \\
  flutter and fall there with a sign.\\
  \hfill \emph{Rabindranath Tagore}
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

$ xelatex test.tex

The end of error messages is like this:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexmf Monaco
! I can't find file `Monaco'.
<*> ...:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input Monaco

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input Monaco

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: Monaco.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input Monaco' failed to make Monaco.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.


!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
!
! The font "Monaco" cannot be found.
!
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
!
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................

l.10

?
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. How did you “install” the font, i.e., make it known to the operating system (here: MacOS)?

Comment: These are Mac OS default fonts. I did not install them by myself. For example, /System/Library/Fonts/Monaco.dfont , and /System/Library/Fonts/Menlo.ttc .

Comment: Please check if the following, minimalist program compiles on your system: `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{fontspec} \setmonofont{Monaco} \begin{document} Monaco \texttt{Monaco} \end{document}`. It compiles on my system (MacOS 10.13.6, MacTeX2018) under XeLaTeX but, interestingly, not under LuaLaTeX.

Comment: XeLaTeX not work for this minimal program. The error message is just like the above one. and I am using Mac OS 10.14.1 (18B75), TexLive2018, not MacTeX2018.

Comment: How did you download/compile/install TeXLive2018 on your system? Incidentally, MacTeX *is* TeXLive -- with a few goodies thrown in to make life (or, at least, using TeX and friends...) easy under MacOS. Is there a downside to downloading and installing MacTeX?

Comment: Off-topic: The `xltxtra` package automatically loads the `fontspec` package -- no need to load `fontspec` separately.

Comment: I used `nix-env -iA texlive-combined-full`. Maybe a bug for `nix` package manager?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `nix`. If you search this site, you will quickly find quite a few postings related to home-brewed versions of TeXLive on MacOS causing lots of grief. Do see if uninstalling texlive and then downloading and installing MacTeX2018 gets the job done.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your information. I am just considering to uninstall it and using homebrew. Smile. I will try MacTeX2018 instead.

Comment: No problem using TeX Live 2018, as installed by MacTeX, with xelatex. On the other hand it won't work with lualatex since that engine doesn't understand .dfont font files..

Comment: @HerbSchulz There's a simple way to convert `.dfont` files. See [Why can't Xetex find my font](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/283286).

Comment: @AlanMunn Does this problem related to  `/System/Library/Fonts/Menlo.ttc`? Menlo fonts also not works.

Comment: @cmal Yes, it's possible. It's been a few years since I looked into this.